# Remove String in Column Name if condition

Tags: r, regex, gsub, grepl

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df

Col+djek    Col_test+deg    Col_+dege     Col_+test
       1               1            1             1
```

In the column name, how do I remove anything after the '+' symbol if the column name does not contain the string 'test'?

This was my attempt but it gave me an error:

```
colnames(df) = if(!grepl(df, "test")){ gsub("+.*","",colnames(df))}
```

Final output should be this:

```
     Col    Col_test+deg         Col_     Col_+test
       1               1            1             1
```

Comment: Try `gsub("^(?!.*test)([^+]*)\\+.*","\\1", colnames(df), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: that did it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub("^(?!.*test)([^+]*)\\+.*","\\1", colnames(df), perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TUovaU/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*test)` - a negative lookahead (supported in PCRE patterns via `perl=TRUE`) that fails the match if after any 0+ chars other than line break chars there is a `test` substring
- `([^+]*)` - Capturing group #1: 0 or more chars other than `+`
- `\\+` - a `+` sign
- `.*` - the rest of the line to the end.

The `\1` in the replacment argument restores the Group 1 value in the resulting string.

An R testing snippet:

```
> names <- c("Col+djek", "Col_test+deg", "Col_+dege", "Col_+test")
> gsub("^(?!.*test)([^+]*)\\+.*","\\1", names, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Col"          "Col_test+deg" "Col_"         "Col_+test"
```